# isinstance check if any of the variables has a certain class

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm having a function that needs to take a different route if any of the parameters is a `np.ndarray`. I'm checking with [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#isinstance). But I wondered if there might be a more intuitive (and faster) way than using a list comprehension together with `any`:

```
def func(a, b):
    if any([isinstance(i, np.ndarray) for i in [a, b]]):
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

I already tried:

```
if isinstance([a, b], np.ndarray):
```

but that doesn't work because `[a, b]` is a `list` ...

Comment: This is not pythonic. Do not check for the type, assume it is and catch an error if it occures. Or cast everything that enters into an array with `np.array(a, copy=False, ndmin=1)`

Comment: By the way, that is not list comprehension; that is a generator expression.  If you put brackets just inside the parenthesis, then you would be passing `any` a list that was created through list comprehension, but as it is, you are passing a generator.

Comment: What @MaxNoe is talking about is a typical coding pattern in Python: https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: There is nothing wrong with checking the type, it is as pythonic as having multiple try/except blocks,  I think the  real problem is how have your application logic designed.

Comment: Normally I would agree but this is a helper-function that should optimize for speed by applying a ``math`` (or custom) function when no variable is a ``ndarray`` and a ``np.ufunc`` if one of them is one. Converting everything to a ``np.ndarray`` would seriously slow things down here.

Comment: Where is the input coming from?

Comment: I have a function that relies on calculating several ``sqrt`` and trigonometric functions and it calls this helper and the helper returns the appropriate math/custom functions if none of them are ``ndarrays`` and np.ufuncs when one is. The problem I encountered was that np.ufuncs are like 10-100 times slower for scalar input then math functions.

Comment: could you not set a flag somewhere?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - That's basically what I want to achieve with this function.

Comment: I mean ever before you get that far, how do you end up in a situation where you don't know what you have in a or b?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Might be that the concept isn't very good but actually I asked myself the original question sometimes and wanted to know if there is any better way of doing it, no matter the use-case. After the initial comment of MaxNoe and albert I'm a bit wary of the chosen approach but that's actually not part of the question and doesn't help solving it. Although many thanks for pointing it out! :-)

Comment: Well the  use-case completely determines what the best approach would be. While saying the logic in your application is off might not be the answer to your question it is probably the most correct answer to your overall problem, if you find yourself doing what you are doing then something is definitely wrong in the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually using `any` is the most pythonic way because it has been implemented in python like following:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

And will return `True` right after encounter a True item in your iterable thus it's order in best case would be O(1) and in worst case O(n). And about the `isinstance()` it's a built in function and is a pythonic way for checking the objects type.

Also as a more pythonic way you better to pass a generator expression  to `any` and let generator function generate the items on demand, instead of a list comprehension and create all the boolean values at once.:

```
any(isinstance(i, np.ndarray) for i in [a, b])
```

As @Padraic said if you are only dealing with two item the best way is using `or` operator:

```
if isinstance(a, np.ndarray) or isinstance(b, np.ndarray):
           # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the generator-hint, I already forgot the brackets (and unintentionally used it as generator expression) and only included the brackets after @zondo pointed it out on the question. :-)

Comment: If you have only two parameters I think `or` would  be the most pythonic  and the fastest approach, `any` should be used when you would find yourself writing multiple or's.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Indeed. Just added your suggestion.